# Open chrome (hidden tab) in C# panel

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome

[Error IMAGE Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT9nG.png)

Hello everyone, I am developing a project and I need to run google chrome application in c # panel, but it is not with the codes in the picture.

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
        public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process p = Process.Start(@"D:\\chrome.lnk");
            p.WaitForInputIdle();
            SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle); //Exception thrown here

        }
```

The text of the exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=İşlemden çıkıldığından istenen bilgiler kullanılamıyor.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       konum: System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState(State state)
       konum: System.Diagnostics.Process.get_MainWindowHandle()
       konum: AnyMinWin.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) c:\users\anyone\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\AnyMinWin\AnyMinWin\Form1.cs içinde: satır 36
       konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       konum: System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       konum: System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       konum: System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       konum: System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       konum: System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       konum: System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       konum: System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       konum: System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       konum: System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       konum: System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       konum: AnyMinWin.Program.Main() c:\users\anyone\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\AnyMinWin\AnyMinWin\Program.cs içinde: satır 18
       konum: System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       konum: System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       konum: Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       konum: System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       konum: System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       konum: System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       konum: System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       konum: System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: The translated to English text of the error is "
The requested information can not be used because the process is exited." (and you still need to put your code in the question)

Comment: I apologize now I have corrected

Answer (score 0):

Just use WebBrowser and set it like:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Navigate("link to you web");
web.Visible = false;
```